# php://input half data lost or truncated on form submit

Tags: php, forms, nginx

I've been looking into this issue for weeks now.

I have a form that manages security permissions for user profiles.
The form submits an array permissions[], with each key being the permission name and another array, as value, with state => boolean and inherited => 0/1.

Like so:

```
permissions => [
    'per1' => [
        'stat' => true,
        'inherited' => 0
    ],
    'per2' => [
        'stat' => false,
        'inherited' => 1
    ],
    (...)
]
```

When the post is submitted, there is a point on the $_POST array that the data is being truncated and corrupted. Is not just fields missing. A chunk of the data is missing.

Here is an example output.

```
"permissions[pos.delete][state]" => "true"
"permissions[pos.delete][inherited]" => "1"
"permissions[pos.edit][state]" => "true"
"permissions[pos.edit][inherited]" => "1"
"permissions[pos.visit_day][stons[uservoucher.view][inherited]" => "1"
"permissions[wallet][state]" => "true"
"permissions[wallet][inherited]" => "1"
"permissions[webgis][inherited]" => ""
"permissions[webgis.map.circuits.edit][inherited]" => ""
"permissions[webgis.map.circuits.edit.all][inherited]" => ""
"permissions[webgis.map.edit][inherited]" => ""
"permissions[webgis.map.view][inherited]" => ""
"permissions[webgis.report.circuit][inherited]" => ""
"permissions[webgis.report.circuit.all][inherited]" => ""
```

On the 5th line you can see my problem. It seems a portion of the post data is lost or truncated and the array gets overlapped.

I ran a tcpdump and check the dump with wireshark and the whole post data seems to be ok. Here is the section of the tcpdump.

```
permissions%5Bpos.delete%5D%5Bstate%5D=true&permissions%5Bpos.delete%5D%5Binherited%5D=1&permissions%5Bpos.edit%5D%5Bstate%5D=true&permissions%5Bpos.edit%5D%5Binherited%5D=1&permissions%5Bpos.visit_day%5D%5Bstate%5D=true&permissions%5Bpos.visit_day%5D%5Binherited%5D=1&permissions%5Bproducts%5D%5Bstate%5D=true&permissions%5Bproducts%5D%5Binherited%5D=1&permissions%5Bproducts.all%5D%5Bstate%5D=true&permissions%5Bproducts.all%5D%5Binherited%5D=1&permissions%5Bproducts.create%5D%5Bstate%5D=true&permissions%5Bproducts.create%5D%5Binherited%5D=1
```

The data seems OK on the dump. But on $_POST and also on php://input the data seems truncated or corrupted.
Here is the section doing a var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'))

```
permissions%5Bpos.delete%5D%5Bstate%5D=true&permissions%5Bpos.delete%5D%5Binherited%5D=1&permissions%5Bpos.edit%5D%5Bstate%5D=true&permissions%5Bpos.edit%5D%5Binherited%5D=1&permissions%5Bpos.visit_day%5D%5Bstons%5Buservoucher.view%5D%5Binherited%5D=1&permissions%5Bwallet%5D%5Bstate%5D=true&permissions%5Bwallet%5D%5Binherited%5D=1&permissions%5Bwebgis%5D%5Binherited%5D=
```

Running nginx 1.8.0 and php 5.6.10 on a centOs 6 dedicated server

Here is my actual php.ini max settings:

```
max_execution_time => 0 => 0
max_file_uploads => 20 => 20
max_input_nesting_level => 512 => 512
max_input_time => -1 => -1
max_input_vars => 10000 => 10000
post_max_size => 100M => 100M
upload_max_filesize => 2M => 2M
```

Ideas ? Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible it's a problem with PHP being non threadsafe when it should be threadsafe? I know if you run it on a webserver, it should be threadsafe

Comment: I am under the impression that when using PHP-FPM, php being thread-safe is not a concern.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I missed that particular detail when reading your post initially. Could it be a problem with PHP itself in this case?

Comment: I'm assuming that's the case, since tcpdump shows all the data is received.